# Print existing report viewer using Shortcut key

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have a Windows form with Report Viewer in it. Currently, I am only able to print using **Print** icon available on top of the form. I have set the **Report** to an **.rdlc** file in design time for Report Viewer control. This is my code in **Load** event of a form:

```
private void BillViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //datas passed to DataSet
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

private void BillViewer_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
            {
                //print report
            }
        }
```

On **KeyDown** event, I want to print the **Report** that is loaded in **ReportViewer** control. How can I do so? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `print` like this

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnKeyDown(e);    
  if ((e.Key == Key.P) && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || 
        Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)))
    reportViewer.PrintDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. You saved my lot of time and effort

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
 {
      if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.P))
      {
          this.crystalReportViewer1.PrintReport();
      }
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
 }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?